# Making animated keyframes text with scss

Tags: html, css, sass

I have seen this codepen project and I don't know how could I make it work in `scss`!

Here is the `CSS` one you can switch to `SCSS` and see it will not work:

https://codepen.io/pigne/pen/XXNrGj

```css
#spin {
  color:red;
}
#spin:after {
  content:"";
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% { content:"ipsum"; }
  10% { content:"dolor"; }
  20% { content:"sit"; }
  30% { content:"amet"; }
  40% { content:"consectetur"; }
  50% { content: "adipisicing"; }
  60% { content: "elit"; }
  70% { content: "Hic"; }
  80% { content: "atque"; }
  90% { content: "fuga"; }
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem <span id="spin"></span>!</p>
```

Could anyone convert it to `SCSS`

Actually it works but does anyone know how to make this work in `SCSS` cause it shows error when I switch to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#spin
  color: red

  &:after
    content: ""
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite

@keyframes spin
  0%
    content: "ipsum"  

  10%
    content: "dolor"  

  20%
    content: "sit"  

  30%
    content: "amet"  

  40%
    content: "consectetur"  

  50%
    content: "adipisicing"

  60%
    content: "elit"

  70%
    content: "Hic"

  80%
    content: "atque"

  90%
    content: "fuga"
```

Maybe [this page](https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, [the site](https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/) you send me did good correction and now its works but the text you send me above wasn't working so i tried [this page](https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/) and its works. Thank you again!